# Last accessed date of a view in tableau server/tableau using rest api

Tags: tableau-api

Is there a way to get the last accessed date of a view in tableau online/server using rest api. I am currently using this
http://my_site/api/3.6/sites/site_id/workbooks/workbook_id/views?includeUsageStatistics=true
but getting usage statics like how many times it was viewed and created date and modified date.

Comment: Are you opposed to using the workgroup database?

Comment: yes I don't want to use the database instead I want to use rest api to get the info

Comment: ok. Just wanted to make sure you were aware of that option.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Views` method in the rest api. I'm using `python` and `tableauserverclient` to get the usage you are looking for. See [TSC reference](https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/api-ref#views) and [Direct Rest API](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref.htm#query_views_for_site) for full docs.

```
import tableauserverclient as TSC
tableau_auth = TSC.TableauAuth('username', 'password')
server = TSC.Server('https://servername')

with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
    all_views, pagination_item = server.views.get()
    for x in all_views:
        print(x.name, x.total_views)
```

The output will look like this and I verified directly in Server.

[image: output]
[image: server direct]

`created_at` and `updated_at` are in the `WorkbookItem` class

I hope that does it for you!

Comment: I am able to fetch the total views using this rest call http://my_site/api/3.6/sites/site_id/workbooks/workbook_id/views?includeUsageStatistics=true ...my question is to get the last accessed date.

Comment: Can we use jdbc to connect to workgroup database from java and retrive that info

Comment: I'm not familiar with the jdbc but doing a quick search seems like its possible. The workgroup database is in PostgreSQL. https://mkyong.com/jdbc/how-do-connect-to-postgresql-with-jdbc-driver-java/     looks promising.